# Resetting user password when devise_for routes are in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-recoverable

In my application all routes are scoped to a locale, that user has selected like this:

```
scope ":locale", locale: /#{SpreeI18n::Config.supported_locales.join('|')}/ do
  devise_for :users, skip: :omniauth_callbacks
  get '/', to: 'homepage#index', :as => :homepage
end
```

When I want to send reset password instructions like `User.find(1).send_reset_password_instructions`, there is a problem:

```
Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 4249.9ms
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords", :reset_password_token=>"-zyuNkscVkwFn2awdm27"} missing required keys: [:locale]
```

How can I pass locale so that I can send the reset token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a custom controller for `password`:

1. Customize **routes.rb**

   ```
   scope ":locale", locale: /#{SpreeI18n::Config.supported_locales.join('|')}/ do
     devise_for :users, skip: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: { passwords: 'my_passwords' }
     get '/', to: 'homepage#index', :as => :homepage
   end
   ```
2. **my_passwords_controller.rb**

   ```
   class MyPasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
     def create
       resource_params.merge!(locale: 'en') # use 'en' for eg
       super
     end
   end
   ```

Then `send_reset_password_instructions` function will take your customized `resource_params` when sending the email.

Please refer to [devise sourcecode](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb) to understand what devise does in detail!